# Is $X_n=Z_1+Z_2+...+Z_n$ a stationary stochastic process if the $Z_i$ are iid?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Consider a random process $X(n) = \{X_n, n\geq 1\}$ where
> $X_n=Z_1+Z_2+...+Z_n$ and the $Z_i$ are iid r,v's with zero mean and
> variance $\sigma^2$. Is $X(n)$ stationary?

The answer is no.

So to tackle this problem we need to know what stationarity is. As I understand it, it is that if a process $X(t)$ is stationary, then $X(t+\tau)$ for any time $\tau$ will have the same distribution as $X(t)$.

Since $Z_n\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ I know that $X_n\sim N(0,n\sigma^2)$ since $\text{var}(\sum_iZ_i)=\sum_i\text{var}(Z_i).$

Now I also want to show that $X_{n+\tau}\nsim N(0,n\sigma^2),$ but this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a stationary process $(X_n)$ the distribution of $X_n$ does not depend on $n$. If you take $(Z_i)$ to be i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ then $X_n \sim N(0, n)$ so the distribution of $X_n$ depends on $n$. In particular the variance of $X_n$ does not remain a constant. Hence $(X_n)$ is not stationary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But does this mean that the definition of a stationary process in my book is wrong? In my book they don't mention the dependence of $n$. How is your definition the same as saying that $\text{Stationarity} \implies X_n \sim X_{n+\tau}$?

Comment: I don't see the difference. If $X_n \sim X_{n+\tau}$ for all $n$ and $\tau$ then $X_n \sim X_1$ for all $n$ so the distribution of $X_n$ does not vary with $n$. @Parseval

Comment: Thanks, my books notation confused me a bit. They used $n$ for something else.